# Cauchy integral with anti-holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I came up with a very stupid question. 
For holomorphic function, we have
$1=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint dz \frac{1}{z}$,
and from its extension, we have famous cauchy-integral formula.

How about anti-holomorphic function?
Is it still holds 
$1=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint d\bar{z} \frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ ?
for $z=R \exp[i\theta]$ and $\bar{z}=R \exp[-i\theta]$ 
using this i obtain $1=-\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint d\bar{z} \frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ 
So i think for anti-holomorphic function, the cauchy-integral formula should change (in terms of sign), i tried to look up some complex algebra textbooks, but they are only talk about holomorphic functions, not anti-holomorphic function. 
Is there some theorem or fourmla like cauchy-integral formula for anti-holomorphic functions?

Comment: If you just take the conjugate of Cauchy's formula, you get an integration formula for $\bar f$, where $f$ is holomorphic. This observation is probably too uninteresting to be mentioned in textbooks. But note that then the integral contains $d\bar z$, as it does in your question. An integral of the form $\oint g(z)\,dz$ with $g$ antiholomorphic is a whole different kettle of fish, however. Employing Green's theorem, you end up with an integral over the interior of the curve.